# Linq - How to to create a list of categories which are included in another table

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I am trying to select from a list of categories where it matches the category type of a list of items using linq. IE, from a list of all the FIGstationeryCategories, select only the ones where the FiGStationeryType has a matching category from an already filtered list. The models are listed below.

```
public class FIGstationeryType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual FIGstationeryCategory Category { get; set; }
    public virtual FIGcompany Company { get; set; }
    public decimal Height { get; set; }
    public decimal Width { get; set; }
    public virtual FIGstationeryType Template { get; set; }
    public bool DoubleSided { get; set; }
}

 public class FIGstationeryCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal MaxZoom { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FIGstationeryType> StationeryItems { get; set; }
}
```

I have been going around in circles with this, and any help will be much appreciated. I haven't got very far! The first line of code works fine, it is the second one I am struggling with.

```
var listOfItems = db.StationeryTypes
            .Where(C => C.Company.Users.Any(u => u.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId))
            .ToList();

       var categoryList = db.StationeryCategories
           .Where(listOfItems
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var listOfCategories = 
(from o in listOfItems select o.Category.Name).Distinct().ToList();
```

When I thought about it (After watching 3 hours of linq videos last night), I realised that the listOfItems already held all the categories which where in use, so I didn't need to query and compare the two tables, just draw the relevant values from the list I already had.

Comment: Hehe sometimes it takes a lot of head banging against hard walls before the obvious becomes obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure how you want to select your categories but this probably goes a little way:

```
var categoryList = db.StationeryCategories
   .*Select*(x => listOfItems.Where(y => y.Category == x)
   .FirstOrDefault());
```

Can you clarify if this is the criteria you are after?

Comment: Select from the  db.stationerycategories table rows only where at least one item in the listOfItems list contains a stationery value equal to that row. (I hope this makes better sense)

I tried your code and got a cannot convert method group where to non delegate type bool error.

Comment: Sorry I do not have a vs environment to test but I think you need a `Select` (or maybe `SelectMany`) not a `Where` at the beginning. Maybe someone else will have a look here and correct my linq to make it work the way you have specified but I will look back later when I have an IDE to test it in.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at my question. I have answered it myself this way: var listOfCategories = (from o in listOfItems select o.Category.Name).Distinct().ToList(); You were right with your select.